# Continous integration of only MyCompanies nuget packages

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, nuget

I am trying to do a nightly package integration with one of our projects that consumes 6 other internal teams’ -PreRelease packages.

**Background Info**

- We have our own internal [ProGet Server](http://inedo.com/proget) that hosts only our company packages.
- Package IDs are in the format of: MyCompany.Project.Component
- We have VS2015 Enterprise ($$), so our build system only has the [VS 2015 Build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) installed.
- We use CruiseControl.NET ( *will be going to TFS later this year* )

**My integration script ( Powershell ) is something like:**

```
#Restores all the packages 1st
nuget restore ( Get-ChildItem $Dir -filter *.sln –Recurse ).FullName 

#Gets all the packages.configs
foreach ( $PackageFile in (Get-ChildItem $RepoDir -filter packages.config -Recurse).FullName )) 
{ 
    #Gets all the packages
    nuget list $PackageFile  

    #Filters my companies packages
    | Select-String -Pattern 'MyCompany.*' –AllMatches 

    #Removes package version and only gets the package ID
    | % { [regex]::Split($_, " ")[0] } 

    #Updates the packages
    | Start-Process nuget -ArgumentList "update $PackageFile -ID $_ -Source MyCompnySrc’s –Prerelease –verbosity detailed" -Wait –NoNewWindow
}
```

Then build the solution, execute unit/integration tests then either check in the new package.configs or report there are some breaking changes.

I thought about splitting MyCompany’s packages into a separate package config but thought it would be wiser to get advice before restructuring all the teams repo’s, and implementing this on other projects.

*I am new to Release Engineering and have that feeling I am making this too complicated*

thanks!

Comment: after reviewing my question it might be more opinion based. Moved to StackExchange [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/308760/continous-integration-of-only-mycompanies-nuget-packages "STE")